# ggplot exact axis range

Tags: r, ggplot2

How do I set the axis range to be exactly as specified?

For the following example, I want the x-axis to cross at 0% (not -0.5% as pictured) and I want the top value to be 12% (not 12.5%)

I have tried both:

```
scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 0.12))
```

and

```
coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 0.12))
```

as per:

[How to set limits for axes in ggplot2 R plots?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606697/how-to-set-limits-for-axes-in-ggplot2-r-plots)

[Can I limit ggplot axis range EXACTLY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48524474/can-i-limit-ggplot-axis-range-exactly)

Sample code:

```
myData = data.frame(x = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                  y = c(0.05,0.06, 0.07, 0.08, 0.09, 0.09))


ggplot() +
  geom_step(data=myData, aes(x=x, y=y), color='orange', size=1) +
  xlab('') +
  ylab('') +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent, limits=c(0,0.12))


ggplot() +
  geom_step(data=myData, aes(x=x, y=y), color='blue', size=1) +
  xlab('') +
  ylab('') +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) + 
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0,0.12))
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you looking for `expand`?

```
coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0,0.12), expand=0)
```

or better (see comments)

```
scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent,
 expand = expand_scale(),
 limits = c(0,0.12))
```

[image]

Comment: Or `scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent, expand = expand_scale(), limits = c(0,0.12)`.

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you.

Comment: `expand_scale()` was deprecated in ggplot2 3.3.0. Now you need to use `expansion()` instead.