# ggplot exact axis range plus reverse

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis

Almost the exact same question as [ggplot exact axis range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59008176/ggplot-exact-axis-range), except I also need to reverse the y-axis from top to bottom.
reprex directly from above

```
myData = data.frame(x = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                  y = c(0.05,0.06, 0.07, 0.08, 0.09, 0.09))

ggplot() +
  geom_step(data=myData, aes(x=x, y=y), color='blue', size=1) +
  xlab('') +
  ylab('') +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = expand_scale(), limits = c(0,5))+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent, expand = expand_scale(), limits = c(0,0.12))

#adding reverse goes wrong
ggplot() +
  geom_step(data=myData, aes(x=x, y=y), color='blue', size=1) +
  xlab('') +
  ylab('') +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = expand_scale(), limits = c(0,5))+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent, expand = expand_scale(), limits = c(0,0.12), trans="reverse")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reverse the `limits` values.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot() +
  geom_step(data=myData, aes(x=x, y=y), color='blue', size=1) +
  xlab('') +
  ylab('') +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = expand_scale(), limits = c(0,5))+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent, expand = expand_scale(),
                     limits = c(0.12,0),trans = "reverse")
```

[image]

Comment: Just came across this...make sure to accept @Ronak Shah's answer if it answers your question! Happy holidays!

Comment: thanks @TheSciGuy. Was back in as remembered to do just that ;-)