# Setting edge of ggplot plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

Is there a way to set the edge of a ggplot bar chart to a particular axis value?

So, for the example below, I would like the right hand edge of the plot to be at 0.4, thus cutting off the "virginica" bar.

```
library(ggplot2)
data("iris")

df <- as.data.frame(data("iris"))
ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = Species, y = Petal.Width/Petal.Length)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "identity") + 
  scale_y_continuous(n.breaks = 9, labels = scales::percent_format(style_negative = "parens")) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

I tried using `coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0,0.4))` as suggested in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48524474/can-i-limit-ggplot-axis-range-exactly) but had no luck. I also tried it with `xlim = c(0,0.4)` in case it being a horizontal bar graph was causing issues but again, no dice.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for `coord_flip(ylim = c(0, 0.4), expand = FALSE)`?

Answer (score -1):

As Allan suggested, you can specify `ylim` extent in `coord-flip`. It can also be specified on its own as below but if you want the edge of the chart to end at the axis extent then you still must specify `expand = FALSE` within `coord-flip`.

```
library(ggplot2)
data("iris")

df <- as.data.frame(data("iris"))
ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = Species, y = Petal.Width/Petal.Length)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "identity") + 
    scale_y_continuous(n.breaks = 9, labels = scales::percent_format(style_negative = "parens")) +
    coord_flip(expand = FALSE) + ylim(c(0,0.4))
```

Comment: You _can't_ use `ylim` on its own. This controls the y axis scale limits, not the co-ordinate limits. This means you would throw away any data that does not fall within the y axis limits. You _need_ to specify it as an argument to the `coord_*` if you want to just "zoom in" without discarding data. Try `ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl, mpg)) + stat_summary(geom = 'bar') + ylim(0, 18)` versus `ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl, mpg)) + stat_summary(geom = 'bar') + coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 18))` to see what I mean.

Comment: @AllanCameron I see your point but it's not relevant to what the op was asking. The code provided above produces the desired chart.